# How Dynamics CRM 2013 Localization process work?

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to know how Dynamics CRM 2013 localize Strings; after investigation, i found that it localize entity labels such as DisplayName in **LocalizedLables** table but what about labels in menus , buttons and controls; there is a table called **DisplayStringBase** but it doesn't contain any localizations; Is Dynamics CRM use resource files or not? I want to know the detailed process of localization in Dynamics CRM 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamics CRM has a supported way to localize the strings, you need to export them as an excel file and import back. Here a tutorial:

http://www.zero2ten.com/blog/crm-2011-online-localization-custom-translations/

The tutorial is for CRM 2011 but the process is the same for CRM 2013.
You can also export the translation of an entire solution, not only a single entity.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help; I already know the steps but i want to know the technical process not from the user perspective;Does CRM use Resource Files(XML) or Database or both together?

Comment: I don't have an official documentation about this, but I think it uses both. Resources files for the language packs (and all the text that is not available for translation) and database to store the localized labels.

Comment: Thanks; Yes it use both Resource files and Database